# removed commits appearing on github commit history

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, version-control, github

I understand that the following  command removes previous  commits to github (^ = ntimes)

```
git push -f origin HEAD^^:master
```

I wanted to remove the last two commits, now when i make some more local changes,

```
git add . 
git commit -m "example"
git push origin master
```

the commits i removed appear again?

What i mean by this is when running

```
git status
```

I get

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.

so the 2 previous commits are there

Anything i need to do to stop this happening

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer if anyone runs into this problem, or if anyone as a better way let us know. Anyway I ran

```
git reset --soft HEAD^^1
```

which undone my last two commits i guess, which then left me up to date. I was then able to run the usual

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin master
```

And all the previous commits where not included